cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 51.104.35.223 port 80: Connection refused
Suddenly I am getting this error on most of my APIs.
Any help will be appreciated.
I am trying to hit GET and POST APIs. Both are giving me this curl issue:

"exception": "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException",
"message": "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 51.104.35.223 port 80: Connection refused (see
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
http://51.104.35.223/Patient?identifier=1313131313",
"file": "/var/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php",
"line": 210,
"trace": "#0 /var/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158):
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
Array)\n#1
/var/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110):

Environment:
  - DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER_ID=${DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER_ID}
  - DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER_GROUP_ID=${DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER_GROUP_ID}
ports:
  - "8599:80" # Accessible from http://localhost within the host machine


"Connection refused" - this sounds more like an infrastructure question. Is 51.104.35.223 up and running, can you connect to that IP over port 80?

Connection refused almost always means either the server isn't running, or there's a firewall blocking the connection.
